# Syntax error when using \n

Tags: python

```
print 'For ' + str(n) ' total pieces:\n' + str(a) + ' six pieces, ' + str(b) + ' nine pieces, ' + str(c) + ' twenty pieces'
```

The interpreter says there is a syntax error and highlights the `'` after `\n`

Comment: Voted to close as too localized because, as the "too localized" description says, this question is unlikely to ever help anyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `+` missing directly after `str(n)`.  The compiler highlights the end of the token that caused the parse error.  In this case, the compiler did not expect a string literal directly after the function call `str(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

For texts such as the one in the question, it's a good idea to use formatted strings, it even helps to prevent errors like the one you're experiencing (a missing `+`):

```
'For %d total pieces:\n%d six pieces, %d nine pieces, %d twenty pieces' % (n,a,b,c)
```

In the above snippet, I'm assuming that `n,a,b,c` are numbers. For more information, take a look at [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) in the documentation.

Comment: If you're going to learn a string formatting system, I suggest learning the [new one](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead of the [old one](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) that Óscar uses in the above answer. Here is how you'd do it then: `'For {0} total pieces:\n{1} six pieces, {2} nine pieces, {3} twenty pieces'.format(n, a, b, c)`. For 2.7+ the numbers inside the curly braces may be omitted if they appear in order.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a '+' before `' total pieces:\n'`.

Really though, this would be a lot nicer as a formatted string.

```
print "For %(total)f total pieces:\n%(six)f six pieces, %(nine)f nine pieces, %(twenty)f twenty pieces" % {
  "total": n,
  "six": a,
  "nine": b,
  "twenty": c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `+` before `' total pieces:\n'`:

```
print 'For ' + str(n) + ' total pieces:\n' + str(a) + ' six pieces, ' + str(b) + ' nine pieces, ' + str(c) + ' twenty pieces'
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `+` in:

```
print 'For ' + str(n) + ' total pieces:\n' + str(a) + ' six pieces, ' + str(b) + ' nine pieces, ' + str(c) + ' twenty pieces'
                      ^
```